# How can i have a link field in a content type display a default text when the field is empty

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-content-types

How can i have a link field in a content type display a default text when the field is empty.

For now i have a field as a link - and the link is set to have a static title. This Works fine.

But i'd like to display a default title if the field is empty with no link (but still rendered as a link/button).

It's not a view - so i can't use "rewrite output if empty".

I'm a newbee to drupal - so please help

This shows what I've got so far:
http://1fb72c32b5e90467b795f388746f7501b3ad8021.web9.temporaryurl.org/tmp/link2.PNG

When the link field is empty the button doesn't show. Instead of not showing when empty I'd like it to show someting like this as default:
http://1fb72c32b5e90467b795f388746f7501b3ad8021.web9.temporaryurl.org/tmp/link3.PNG (the button "Bestil på tlf...")

Comment: Hi @jan and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you provide an example of the code you are working with, or possible some screenshots showing what you are trying to achieve? It is very hard to understand your question as it stands.

Comment: Hi @BjarkeFreund-Hansen - thanks. I can't attach screenshots because I only have one reputation point .-)

Comment: worked around it by adding links to screen shots. And here's the link to the settings. http://1fb72c32b5e90467b795f388746f7501b3ad8021.web9.temporaryurl.org/tmp/link1.PNG

Answer (score 0):

By simply using [**`Link`**](http://drupal.org/project/link) module, i don't think this is possible. But, follow below steps in your environment and i think you might achieve the goal:

- Make custom template file for the page (i think, its product details page)
- In that template file, check whether the link is empty or not
- If link is not empty, show the link. If link is empty, show your custom HTML.

Comment: thanks Bhavik. I've had the same thoughts. My problem is that I don't know how to code it. (I would probably find the right template) but could you please start me of in the right direction with som sample code? This would be my first time to really altering a template.